# Idea of 'parser' to make the writing of asynchronous functions chains easier

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Why this thing :

I work on a project where I need to call many asynchronous functions to get data, chain them, execute them if conditions are met,.. and I ended up having unreadable code. 
 
At some point, I looked at promises library like Q.js but even with such tools my code was complicated, so I decided to write something which would make my cases of use simple to read.

### Code + what it does :

The whole concept is to help someone generate the code for the asynchronous calls as a string and then call eval() to run it (the latter probably being a major case of evil programming). 
 At the moment, it has only two functions because I am not sure how good this idea is.

**First function : chain** 
*This functions chains two asynchronous calls, optionally with a condition on the result of the first asynchronous call.*

```
pp_chain_function = function (fname,condition_string) {
var queue=this;
var prec_result = 'result_'+queue.queue_length;
queue.queue_string += !condition_string ? '.then(function(){return '+fname+'();})'
        :'.then(function('+prec_result+'){if('+prec_result+condition_string+'){return '+fname+'();}return $.when();})';
queue.length++;

return queue;
};
```

**Second function : fail** 
 *Adds fail handler for the whole queue.*

```
pp_fail_function = function(fname) {
    var queue = this;
    queue.queue_string += '.fail(function(error){return '+fname+'(error);})';
    return queue;
};
```

**Global queue prototype :**

```
queue_object = {
        pp_chain : pp_chain_function,
        pp_fail : pp_fail_function
        };
```

**Initializing the queue :**

```
pp_begin = function(){
    var pp_queue = Object.create(queue_object); 
    pp_queue.queue_string='$.when()';
    pp_queue.queue_length=0;
    console.warn(pp_queue);
    return pp_queue;
};
```

### Usage case :

```
var chain = pp_begin(); //init the chain
    chain.pp_chain('async_0').pp_chain('async_1');  //add two standard async functions
    if(condition two){chain.pp_chain('async_2','.length>0');} //if external conditions and async_1 gave a result with length>0, execute async_2
    chain.pp_fail('fail_handler');  //add fail handler
    console.warn(chain);  //replace with eval if you want to actually run it
```

I would love some feedback on that idea mainly, and on the code if applicable (even if there is very few).

**EDIT** : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afSub/2/) for up-to-date version

#### Concrete example :

***Before :***

```
 if (online_mode && i_s_r) { //if sync clear collections and reload them
            access.findAll()
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (result.length > 0) {
                        access.remove(result, {
                                push: false
                            })
                            .then(function () {
                                access.load()
                                    .then(function () {
                                        callback_function(i, true);
                                    });
                            });
                    } else {
                        access.load()
                            .then(function () {
                                callback_function(i, true);
                            });
                    };
                })
                .fail(function (errorObject) {
                    alert(errorObject);
                });
        } else {
            callback_function(i, true);
```

***After :***

```
var q0 = begin(); 
        if(online_mode && i_s_r){q0.chain('access.findAll()').chain('access.remove(result_1,{push: false})','.length>0').chain('access.load()').failure('alert');}
        q0.chain_sync('callback_function(i,true)');
        eval(q0.queue_string);
```

Comment: Do a search for: "javascript async await semantics," these tools are great for solving the problem of deeply nested callback functions. Eg: https://github.com/bjouhier/galaxy

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question,

I find this code hard to read, I wonder what you consider *unreadable code*.

Some remarks on

```
pp_chain_function = function (fname,condition_string) {
var queue=this;
var prec_result = 'result_'+queue.queue_length;
queue.queue_string += !condition_string ? '.then(function(){return '+fname+'();})'
        :'.then(function('+prec_result+'){if('+prec_result+condition_string+'){return '+fname+'();}return $.when();})';
queue.length++;

return queue;
};
```

- Use jsbeautifier.org, always
- Prefixing with `pp` makes no good sense
- Postfixing with `_string` makes little sense
- `prec_result` <- What does prec stand for
- `var queue=this;`, you only need to re-assign `this` if you work with closures
- Consider a templating function for your string building
- That long ternary statements looks horrendous, consider splitting it over multiple lines

Some remarks on

```
queue_object = {
    pp_chain : pp_chain_function,
    pp_fail : pp_fail_function
};
```

- You use `queue_object` as a prototype, consider changing the name to reflect, also, JavaScript ought to be written in lowerCamelCase: `queue_object` -> `queueObject` -> `queuePrototype`

Some remarks on

```
var chain = pp_begin(); //init the chain
    chain.pp_chain('async_0').pp_chain('async_1');  //add two standard async functions
    if(condition two){chain.pp_chain('async_2','.length>0');} //if external conditions and async_1 gave a result with length>0, execute async_2
    chain.pp_fail('fail_handler');  //add fail handler
    console.warn(chain);  //replace with eval if you want to actually run it
```

- Indenting is messed up
- You are putting conditions in strings..
- I am fairly certain that either by making `async_1` fail if length < 1 or putting your check inside async_2 you could replace this with

  ```
  $.when( async_0, async_1 )
    .then( async_2, fail_handler );
  ```

The biggest elephant in the room is of course `eval`, you loose proper stack-traces, debugging, tooling ( jshint, jsbeautifier ), and open yourself up to all kinds of pain. I would suggest that you post one of your unreadable scripts, perhaps we can show you how to use Q so that they become readable without resorting to .. this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; some questions/answers : - prec stands for precedent which is french for previous (mistake, I'll replace it with previous) -  - Why shouldn't I put conditions in strings? - I can not modify the asynchronous functions' code, otherwise it would indeed be simpler =P - By templating fuction, do you mean I should store the template string somewhere with dummy args and use .replace()? - all the points I did not mention make sense to me and I'll try to make the corresponding changes

Comment: +1 for "post one of your unreadable scripts." I would really like to see a before and after example. As it is I can't imagine this making anything more readable.

Comment: Posted a case of use, well I don't know if it is more readable but it is shorter for sure =P Of course it could be improved further but I am still not quite sure how good the concept is..